# Cerber - why were some files not encrpted?

Tags: windows-10, malware

I was hit by *Cerber* on the weekend.

This surprised me given I was running Grindsoft Anti-Malware in addition to Defender, although I suspect Grindsoft real-time protection was off given there had been an issue with the activation license (I was issued with a new key but only noted post infection that protection was now off).

It came in via another User Account, I saw what was happening in time to kill the net before my encrypted OneDrive files were uploaded to the cloud, regardless of which I had back-ups of my important personal files.

I removed the malware with GRindsoft, re-installed Windows and then my restored my backed-up files.

- My incremental back-up file (around 500Mb) on an external drive was not impacted (while all documents on an USB were encrypted). I won't specify the back-up program here.
- All `*.iso` files were also untouched.

Is it likely that *Cerber* skipped these files because of the file type and/or file size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link below has a list of file extensions used by Cerber:

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/the-cerber-ransomware-not-only-encrypts-your-data-but-also-speaks-to-you/

.iso is not in the list but Cerber uses a config file that stores a list of file extensions to target.  This makes Cerber more flexible since the list of file extensions is easily modified.